# Where does Lion Server store apps used for iOS deployment?

Tags: applications, server.app, profile-manager

I was messing around with the "Edit Apps" feature in the Profile Manager. I saw the "Edit Apps" button and I uploaded an app to test it.

Unfortunately it was a commercial app, so I cannot actually deploy it to an iOS device (in fact it errors when trying to add it).

Now that I'm done playing, I'd like to delete it from my server, but I have no idea where to find it, and the Profile Manager doesn't allow the deletion of apps.

Where does Lion Server store apps (ipa files) used for iOS deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the files are stored in /Library/Server/ProfileManager/Data/FileStore but are not stored as IPA files.

Comment: Yep can confirm this on 10.8 and 10.9 as at time of writing; just add the IPA extension and they work as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to delete the profile that contained the upload to cleanly delete the app.

If not, use mdfind in the terminal to find the ipa file.

Comment: I've tried `mdfind SoundMeter` which is the name of the app `(SoundMeter 592.ipa)`, and the results come up empty. I'm not sure what you mean by deleting the profile.